# Copying from one table to another using sql (sql*plus)

Tags: sql, sqlplus

This is something pretty simply and I see there are many posts on the website but I cannot get it to work for me.

Heres what I am trying to do:  Copy from data from table "student".  Student contains three columns: studentID, name, and major.

I need this data copied into another table called "dw_student".

Here is what I have so far for this:

```
INSERT INTO dw_student (studentID, name, major, studentKey)
SELECT studentID, name, major, STUDENTSEQ.nextval
FROM student
```

Studentseq.nextval assigns a unique number to each row.  It works in other places in my code so far.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Here is Studentseq.nextval:

```
create sequence STUDENTSEQ increment by 1 start with 4000; 
drop table holdcounter3; 
CREATE TABLE holdcounter3 
( PKsequence3 number(5), 
 dataname1 char(4), 
 CONSTRAINT pk_sequence3 PRIMARY KEY (PKsequence3) );
```

Comment: In MSSQL I'm sure you don't have to name all the columns, just use 
`INSERT INTO dw_student
    SELECT studentID, name, major, STUDENTSEQ.nextval
    FROM student `
What is "STUDENTSEQ.nextval"? A sql function? What is the error message?

Comment: I added the STUDENTSEQ code to show what it does.  There is no error message, just nothing is added.

Comment: @StefanBrendle: you don't *have* to list the columns for an INSERT statement, but it's good coding style and makes your code more robust and maintainable.

Comment: @user2317112: what exactly is your question? Do you get an error? If yes, which one? Does it copy the wrong data?

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was just syntax with oracle.  I went to answer the question but it wouldn't let me since I have a low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax looks fine. Make sure you issue a `COMMIT` to have the results permanently saved. Otherwise the transaction will be discarded when you exit sql*plus. Transactions are not automatically commited in sql*plus.